# Query does not filter from two values separated by | in NOT CONTAINS string

Tags: regex, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I'm using the formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRIM(IMPORTXML("https://www.livescores.com/","//div[@class='content']//div[contains(@class,'row-gray')]")),"Where not Col1 contains 'Postp|Canc' "))`

But for some reason `'Postp|Canc'` not removing the lines that contain such values, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` is a regex thing and in query only `matches` is regex attribute. use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRIM(IMPORTXML("https://www.livescores.com/",
 "//div[@class='content']//div[contains(@class,'row-gray')]")),
 "where not Col1 matches '.*Postp.*|.*Canc.*'"))
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRIM(IMPORTXML("https://www.livescores.com/",
 "//div[@class='content']//div[contains(@class,'row-gray')]")),
 "where not Col1 contains 'Postp' 
     or not Col1 contains 'Canc'"))
```

Comment: I'm waiting for the 7 minutes to mark your answer as the solution, I only have one issue please. Instead of ```+``` it is necessary to use ```*```. I tested it with ```+``` and it didn't work, but with ```*``` it worked. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I would like to propose to modify the xpath. The modified xpath is as follows.

#### Modified xpath:

```
//div[@class='content']//div[div[@class='min'][not(contains(text(),'Postp') or contains(text(),'Canc'))]]
```

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.livescores.com/","//div[@class='content']//div[div[@class='min'][not(contains(text(),'Postp') or contains(text(),'Canc'))]]")
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)